# Link to exposed filter

Tags: views, navigation

I have a view with two exposed filters. When a user changes the filter criteria, the results change accordingly. I need the URL that shows what the view is currently showing, with the current filter criteria.

How do I find the correct URL?

Answer (score 1):

To find the generated URL for an exposed filter, select the filter in the view -> scroll to the bottom -> click More -> look under Filter identifier. Copy and paste this after the url (e.g. www.mysite.com/myview?**field_story_category_tid**=3). To identify a specific filter, get the number from the URL aliases page (admin/config/search/path).